# How to remove id & name attributes from rails view helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, helper, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails generates id and name for `select_tag` from name argument by default:

```
select_tag "people", "<option>David</option>".html_safe
# => <select id="people" name="people"><option>David</option></select>
```

***But what if we want to generate `select` without and `id` and `name` attributes?***
Like this:

```
<select><option>David</option></select>
```

Empty name argument doesn't work, empty html attributes still exists:

```
select_tag "", "<option>David</option>".html_safe
# => <select id name><option>David</option></select>
```

Manual `id` and `name` assign doesn't work

```
select_tag "people", "<option>David</option>".html_safe, id: false, name: false
# => <select id=false name=false><option>David</option></select>
select_tag "people", "<option>David</option>".html_safe, id: '', name: ''
# => <select id name><option>David</option></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` and `name` can be removed by assigning `nil` to it:

```
select_tag nil, "<option>David</option>".html_safe, id: nil
# => <select><option>David</option></select>
```